# Order, bucket sort, and order buckets of NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, key-value

I have an `NSArray` of `Object` that has an interesting `property` that I would like to use in the following way: Given my array of objects with properties:

`Object1 - Property A`;
`Object2 - Property A`;
`Object3 - Property B`;
`Object4 - Property D`;
`Object5 - Property D`;
`Object6 - Property D`

I want these to be bucket sorted by their properties into a new array:

`Array1 - Objects Object1, Object2`

`Array2 - Objects Object3`

`Array3 - Objects Object 4, Object5, Object6`

And then within each array, sort by using a `timeStamp` property.

I have tried to accomplish this naively by creating a dictionary, adding interesting objects to the dictionary by property like `if ([dictionary objectForKey:@"propertyVal"]) //add object else // create array for key, add object to array`. This approach has not worked as expected because I end up needing to dekey the `NSMutableDictionary` using `allKeysForValue`, which is not reliable.

I feel that this is a fairly common problem and I would love to hear any insight into how I might go about solving this. Code is great, but even an algorithm (with the appropriate objects to use) should suffice.

Comment: Using a dictionary of arrays sounds reasonable. Explain what you mean by "dekey the NSMutableDictionary", why you need to do that, and how it failed. Also, there is no `-[NSDictionary allKeysForValue]`, do you mean `allKeysForObject`?

Comment: Yes, I meant `allKeysForObject`. It returns `nil` when I pass in the original string.

Comment: Again, explain what "dekey the NSMutableDictionary" means to you, because it isn't clear. When you're done building the dictionary, you should be able to iterate through the keys and values (the arrays) quite easily, without needing `-allKeysForObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a proper bucket sort, but should work for a set of three properties. A bit of fiddling and you should be able to adjust it for any number of properties:

Edit. I made a dynamic version (just set property type to what you need):

```
- (NSMutableArray *)order:(NSDictionary *)objects byProperty:(id)property {
    NSMutableSet *propertySet = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:5]; // so we can count the unique properties
    for (Object *obj in [objects allValues]) {
        [propertySet addObject:[obj property]];
    }

    NSMutableArray *objectCollections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[propertySet count]];

    // create arrays for every property
    for (int i = 0; i < [objects allValues]; i++) {
        NSMutableArray *collection = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5];
        [objectCollections addObject:collection];
    }  
    NSArray *allProperties = [propertySet allObjects];

    // push objects into arrays according to a certain property
    for (Object *obj in [dictionary allValues]) {
        [[objectCollections objectAtIndex:[allProperties indexOfObject:[obj property]] addObject:obj];
    }

    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[objectCollections count]];
    // sort arrays by timestamp
    for (int i = 0; i < [objectCollections count]; i++) {
            [result addObject:[[objectCollections objectAtIndex:i] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
            if ([(Object *)obj1 timeStamp] > [(Object *)obj2 timeStamp]) {
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
            }
            if ([(Object *)obj1 timeStamp] < [(Object *)obj2 timeStamp]) {
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
            }            
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
        }];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that creating the arrays "up front" is not viable since I do not necessarily know what the properties A,B,C... will be. They could be anything.

Comment: Well, then wrap everything in a function and make it dynamic. You can use the general pattern of my solution and parametrize it.

Comment: `[__NSCFString beginDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x69762c0` when I try to do the comparison `if ([(WSConference *)obj1 beginDate] > [(WSConference *)obj2 beginDate])` ... and I am using ARC, and `beginDate` is a `strong, nonatomic` `@property`

Comment: Nevermind, that his been resolved, but it is still failing... I will try debugging further. Your method looks promising

Comment: I edited my post with a better version. For your last comment - it seems that you cant extract the beginDate property from your object (have you synthesized it?)